# Merge two columns and add one extra column filled with headers from the two first column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have this:

```
Date          Header1           Header2      
01/01/2016  value_header1_1    value_header2_1
02/01/2016  value_header1_2    value_header2_2
03/01/2016  value_header1_3    value_header2_3
04/01/2016  value_header1_4    value_header2_4
05/01/2016  value_header1_5    value_header2_5
```

and I want this :

```
Date          Header1         Extra column       
01/01/2016  value_header1_1   header1    
02/01/2016  value_header1_2   header1 
03/01/2016  value_header1_3   header1 
04/01/2016  value_header1_4   header1 
05/01/2016  value_header1_5   header1 
01/01/2016  value_header2_1   header2
02/01/2016  value_header2_2   header2
03/01/2016  value_header2_3   header2
04/01/2016  value_header2_4   header2
05/01/2016  value_header2_5   header2
```

I've already start by using the following formula:

```
=transpose(split(join(";",'Daily data'!B1:B,'Daily data'!C1:C),";"))
```

But then I'm stuck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the columns you show are A:C, the following formula works:

```
={filter({A2:A, B2:B, iferror(A2:A/0, "header1")}, len(A2:A)); filter({A2:A, C2:C, iferror(A2:A/0, "header2")}, len(A2:A))}
```

The first part forms a three-column array in which the third column is "header1" (created by artificially throwing an error of division by zero and putting "header1" with `iferror`). The second does the same, but using A and C instead of A and B. In both cases, the filter makes sure we don't include the rows there A is empty. Finally, the two arrays are stacked using vertical-stack notation `{array1; array2}`.